# 'Close' button in Storyboard won't link to IBAction in view controller.swift to dismiss a window

Tags: cocoa, swift3, interface-builder

Hello all you smart people! I am very new to Xcode 8 and Swift3, and am bringing a new meaning to the phrase 'killer app'. It'll kill me before it gets a chance to provide my pension!!! :-)

My OSX app is a stay resident app in the top right of the apple menu (info.plist set to Application is Agent(UIElement)= True). The main function of the app, executing an applescript, works fine. It is run from the app menu icon or key combo. I've added an 'about' window and the window appears if I select 'about' from the App menu and it closes if I click the red circle. However I can't seem to get an (interface) close button to close the window.

The 'about' window is generated from an NSMenuItem in AppDelegate.swift as in the code below. All I'm trying to do is close said window with a close button in the (viewcontroller)interface. It's that simple but no matter what I try I cannot link the close button in the Storyboard viewcontroller to an IBAction in viewcontroller.swift so as to add window!.close. The only option given is a 'represented object' binding. It's not possible to link to an IBAction in AppDelegate.swift either. 
t must be something to do with the way the window is generated because if I build an app with a normal apple menu the interface buttons will link to actions in the code. If anyone can help please email me at pauljvallance@icloud.com and I can send you the Xcode 8.2.1 project and Swift3 code. Best regards, Paul

```
func windowAbout(sender: NSMenuItem){

     let mainStoryboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     myWindowController = mainStoryboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "aboutWindowController") as!
     NSWindowController
     myWindowController.showWindow(self)
      }
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the relevant storyboard(s)?

Comment: Sorry @paul I can't see how to upload an image here. However, image and code are here [link] (http://www.menantol.co.uk/thingsthingy)

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 8 appears to have introduced a bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66022) that prevents you from making connections by dragging from an Interface Builder element to a view controller method *when the method in question is defined in a class extension*. You can however create the desired connection by dragging from your method to the relevant UI element in Interface Builder:

[image]

Comment: thanks Paul but that solution doesn't work for me. I think its because UI Agents aren't supposed to be handled in this way, with dialogs. Never mind. The user can click the tiny little red button at top right of the window to dismiss the dialog.